# Title on DialogFragment

Tags: java, android, gridview, dialog

I want to create a simple dialog that has a grid view in the middle and lets the user choose a letter.

Here is the XML I started with following: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html and some others:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/gridview"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:columnWidth="90dp"
              android:numColumns="auto_fit"
              android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
              android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
              android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
              android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then I have this code to use it:

```
package com.example.activity;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;

/**
 * Select a letter from the dialog
 */
public class SelectLetterDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    GridView gridView;

    static final String[] numbers = new String[] {
            "A", "B", "C", "D", "E",
            "F", "G", "H", "I", "J",
            "K", "L", "M", "N", "O",
            "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T",
            "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.setTitle("Select a letter");

        return dialog;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.select_letter_dialog, container);

        gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String letter = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
                Log.e("Blah", letter);
                dismiss();
            }
        });

        setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);

        return  view;
    }
}
```

So this creates a dialog with just a grid with letters on it. This confuses me. So first question is, what does `dialog.setTitle("Select a letter")` do since it doesn't appear to affect this?

So then I changed the XML file to add a TextView to put the title in like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select a Letter"
        />
    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/gridview"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:columnWidth="90dp"
              android:numColumns="auto_fit"
              android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
              android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
              android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
              android:gravity="center"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

And now the letters are in a single column. So my second question is, WTF? Why is this behaving this way?

My third and real question is how do I get a title on my dialog with the letters four across in a grid like the first example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did get GridLayout or GridView to work properly. I ended up just adding LinearLayouts and setting the width on them so they worked into a grid. Using styles made it better.

Answer (score 0):

Using some of your snippet:

```
public void customDialog(){
   Dialog dialog=new Dialog(this);
   dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
   dialog.setContentView(R.layout.select_letter_dialog);
   dialog.getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.custom_title);
   dialog.show();
}
```

res/layout/custom_title.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text="This is a custom title"/>
```

Comment: This is no longer a recommended method.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment of onCreateDialog:
[image]
I think you can try to move the code in onCreateView to onCreateDialog, and then delete onCreateView. like this:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.select_letter_dialog);
    dialog.setTitle("Select a letter");
    gridView = (GridView) dialog .findViewById(R.id.gridview);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(view.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, numbers);

    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                int position, long id) {
            String letter = ((TextView) v).getText().toString();
            Log.e("Blah", letter);
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    setStyle(STYLE_NORMAL, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog);

    return  dialog;
}
```

Comment: I'm not using AlertDialog

Answer (score 0):

In your previous code (reason for 2nd question)

android:numColumns="auto_fit (in grid)
android:layout_width="wrap_content" (in parent layout)

so its showing you letters in the single line (taking space as much of title)

And its solution is to set

android:numColumns = 4 (in grid)
android:layout_width="match_parent" (in parent layout)

Comment: This did not fix my problem.